# Is "flair" a Stack Exchange trademark?

Tags: discussion, support, flair, trademark, intellectual-property

I'm not very good with subtlety and this doesn't appear to be in the context of a joke.

On my [flair page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/374/xiaohouzi79?tab=flair) it has the following:

> It's a piece of valuable flair<sup>tm</sup> you can place on any website to show
>   off your user profile!

Is flair really a trademarked term or am I missing some MSO joke which has somehow spread into other sites?

Comment: I'd always assumed it was a reference to [Office Space](http://movieclips.com/rZXFU-office-space-movie-flair-minimum)...

Comment: See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/nowearn-valuable-flair/ sadly the youtube video has been yanked...there's another clip here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bsl2Wa32u1s